# Intellisense is not suggesting MonoBehaviour methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Intellisense works almost exactly as it should, however, when I'm in a class and start typing in void On(event) Intellisense doesn't auto-suggest MonoBehaviour methods like OnMouseOver or OnMouseExit. Nor does it suggest the Start or Update methods. Also, note that I'm using visual studio 2019 and Unity 2017. It also says that the current project is Assembly-CSharp.

Example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/asLrn.jpg

I've tried restarting my PC, Unity, Visual Studio. I've also tried manually telling unity to use Visual Studio 2019.

If I started typing in:

```
public GameObject object;
```

Visual Studio automatically starts suggesting things when I get to G.

If I started typing in:

```
void OnMouseEnter()
{

}
```

It doesn't suggest any Monobehaviour methods after void.

It should start suggesting things after void.
In practice, it doesn't and only really suggests things in other situations.

Comment: Have you tried typing `void override`?  I've never had it suggest it after typing the return type only after specifically going to override something.

Comment: After override it suggests things but, it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problem by telling unity to use Visual Studio 2017 and then opening the solution in Visual Studio 2019.